# Can' t find condition to stop simple telnet server on python

Tags: python, sockets, server, port, telnet

I want to create simple server. But condition for closing of connection by server isn't satisfies.

```
import socket
soc = socket.socket()
soc.bind(('', 33333))
soc.listen(2)
(conn, address) = soc.accept()
while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    conn.sendall(data)
    if(data == 'stop'):
        conn.close()
        break
```

Ubuntu bash after running of this code:

```
~$ telnet localhost 33333
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
stop
stop
```

Comment: Try if data.startswith('stop'):. When you send 'stop' from telnet, it includes a line terminator (e.g. '\r\n').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `data` actually equals to `'stop\r\n'`.

Use [str.strip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) to remove the line terminator:

```
if data.strip() == 'stop':
```

EDIT: Consider acquiring `data` using:

```
data = ''
while not data.endswith('\n'):
    data += conn.recv(1024)
```

You might also want to read the [Socket Programming HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/sockets.html) from the official documentation.

Comment: it's not that simple, you don't know if recv actually received all the data, or just 2 bytes.

Comment: Anyone coming across this in the future, do not use this. It is just a cheap hack that seems to work. TCP sockets are stream based not packet based, so you will send 4 bytes, but the receiving end may receive 1 byte at a time. When this happens the variable data will only carry 1 byte at a time and will never equal 'stop'. Just because something works in a test case doesn't mean it actually works. If I was comfortable in python i'd add a proper answer myself. On a side note, the OP said he is using Ubuntu where the line terminator is actually '\n', its '\r\n' on windows.

Comment: I just learn about sockets and protocols. This code not for practical usage but experiment for better understanding. Strange but for me works only with'\r\n' with ubuntu 12.10

Comment: this here is probably a good read http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.ca/2013/05/sockets-are-byte-streams-not-message.html its best to learn how tcp works rather than take advice from someone who clearly doesn't understand sockets. Like I said before. Tcp is stream based meaning I could send 2 times and receive once as well. pretend I send 'hello\n' and 'world\n'. on the receiving end I could get 'hello\nworld\n' in one recv call. In fact, if you have access to a windows computer try using telnet with your program. It won't work because windows telnet sends a packet every single time you type.

Comment: @WalterM You have a point about the sockets being stream based, but your comment is disproportionate. This answer directly addresses OP's issue and is not meant to be a guide to socket programming.

Comment: Thanks for answers guys)